# Download area designated by a bounding box of Microsoft's USBuildingFootprints dataset

Tags: r, building

I would like to plot some houses in a relatively small area of MD, the bounding box is:  xmin: -76.12, ymin: 38.05, xmax: -75.68, ymax: 38.42

Microsoft's USBuildingFootprints dataset can be downloaded by state here https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints, but is there another way to download just a requested area, in order to get around the large files and slow download speeds?

I would prefer a solution using R or an internet browser.

Comment: Via the ArcGIS REST Server connection in at https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/ I can see (in QGIS) lots of layers including MSBFP. I can select "only request features overlapping the view extent" and I see buildings, so that must be subsetting by box. If you can fabricate a query for that REST server with a bounding box you should be able to get a subset....

Comment: I think its accessible via the ESRIJSON OGR driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/esrijson.html which means you might be able to get it with `st_read` but the exact query string to access within a bounding box needs creating...

Comment: It seems like this approach would work with any of the layers on the ArcGIS Rest server. Maybe it would be helpful to users to point that out. I could add it in the question or just ask another generalized question about downloading any layer using R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in R, construct a URL string like this with your bounding box encoded in it. Use `paste0` or some other string concatenation function to build it. This is based on @user30184 answer:

```
url="https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/MSBFP2/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry={%22xmin%22:-76.12,%22ymin%22:38.05,%22xmax%22:-75.68,%22ymax%22:38.42,%22spatialReference%22:{%22wkid%22:4326}}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&outSR=4326"
```

Then you can use `st_read` from the `sf` package:

```
bdgs = st_read(url)
```

Getting about 11,000 buildings:

```
dim(bdgs)
## [1] 11978     2
```

Your `sf` needs to be linked with a GDAL/OGR that supports these servers:

```
> st_drivers()["ESRIJSON",]
             name long_name write  copy is_raster is_vector  vsi
ESRIJSON ESRIJSON  ESRIJSON FALSE FALSE     FALSE      TRUE TRUE
```

If that returns NA values then your GDAL/OGR needs upgrading/rebuilding.

Here's an R function that downloads the buildings given some bounding coordinates in WGS84::

```
get_buildings <- function(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax){
    URL = paste0("https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/",
                 "ArcGIS/rest/services/MSBFP2/FeatureServer/0/",
                 "query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&",
                 "spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&",
                 "geometry={",
                 "%22xmin%22:",xmin,
                 ",%22ymin%22:",ymin,
                 ",%22xmax%22:",xmax,
                 ",%22ymax%22:",ymax,
                 ",%22spatialReference%22:{%22wkid%22:4326}}&",
                 "geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&outSR=4326")
    st_read(URL, quiet=TRUE)

}
```

giving:

```
> bb = get_buildings(-76.12, 38.05, -75.68, 38.42)
> bb
Simple feature collection with 11978 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -76.1202 ymin: 38.04976 xmax: -75.67844 ymax: 38.42065
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
   BlockgroupID                       geometry
1  240399303001 POLYGON ((-75.74032 38.0858...
2  240399303002 POLYGON ((-75.7885 38.1083,...
3  240199709002 POLYGON ((-76.11691 38.3538...
4  240199709002 POLYGON ((-76.11554 38.3529...
5  240450108004 POLYGON ((-75.91377 38.2617...
6  240450108004 POLYGON ((-75.87707 38.3167...
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Spacedman wrote in the comment, building footprint data seems to be available from the ESRI service.

The documentation about the REST API is at https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-.htm. Basic command for getting data from a BBOX that is expressed as EPSG:4326 coordinates, and output also in EPSG:4326, is like this:

[https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/MSBFP2/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry={"xmin":-76.12,"ymin":38.05,"xmax":-75.68,"ymax":38.42,"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&outSR=4326](https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/MSBFP2/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22:-98,%22ymin%22:35,%22xmax%22:-97.9,%22ymax%22:35.1,%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:4326%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&outSR=4326)

You can use the URL with ogrinfo and ogr2ogr. In this test with your coordinates the URL is url-encoded because otherwise I GDAL was throwing an error.

```
ogrinfo "https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/MSBFP2/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry={%22xmin%22:-76.12,%22ymin%22:38.05,%22xmax%22:-75.68,%22ymax%22:38.42,%22spatialReference%22:{%22wkid%22:4326}}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&outSR=4326" -al |more
INFO: Open of `https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/MSBFP2/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry={%22xmin%22:-76.12,%22ymin%22:38.05,%22xmax%22:-75.68,%22ymax%22:38.42,%22spatialReference%22:{%22wkid%22:4326}}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&outSR=4326'
      using driver `ESRIJSON' successful.

Layer name: ESRIJSON
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 11978
Extent: (-76.120200, 38.049758) - (-75.678439, 38.420649)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
BlockgroupID: String (12.0)
OGRFeature(ESRIJSON):0
  BlockgroupID (String) = 240399302002
  POLYGON ((-75.9405880296284 38.1716720350858,-75.9408220407599 38.1716180090955,-75.940838030772 38.1716600293136,-75.9406040196404 38.1717149733605,-75.9405880296284 38.1716720350858))

OGRFeature(ESRIJSON):1
  BlockgroupID (String) = 240399302001
  POLYGON ((-75.9427420100167 38.1518889956417,-75.9426950281273 38.1519089871405,-75.9426629582717 38.1518639886001,-75.9427100299926 38.151843997089,-75.9427420100167 38.1518889956417))
...
```

Comment: I've coded that string into an R solution!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would also accept your answer if picking more than one was allowed.